# syntax highlighting XAML Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, syntax-highlighting

I experience some problem with Visual Studio 2015, when I re-installed on my computer, the whole syntax highlighting became all white in XAML, but not in my VB code?

If someone happens to find the solution, I would be extremely grateful to him.

[visualization code in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qARO.png)

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what problem you're facing, is the above snippet being highlighted red by VS2015?

Comment: Can we see the VB visualization code?

Comment: All the color you see in the exemple was blank on all my project in VS2015