# XAML syntax highlighting missing

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

After a clean installation of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, on a brand new Surface Pro 4 running Windows 10, my XAML syntax highlighting is missing. I've got XAML syntax highlighting on 3 other computers that run Windows and Visual Studio; this machine for some reason doesn't have it.

I tried [resetting the user data](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e6bf2ba-a1e6-440a-a8d5-14868883be84/missing-xaml-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=csharpide) in Visual Studio and I noticed this *prior* to installing any extensions. It seems like I'm [not the only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541270/syntax-highlighting-xaml-visual-studio) one to have this issue. What steps need to be performed in order for my syntax highlighing to return? The Intellisense seems to work without issue, just the highlighting is missing.

Note that I've also tried resetting the environment fonts & colors back to defaults; didn't fix the issue. My C# and Sql syntax highlighting work without any problems.

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e6bf2ba-a1e6-440a-a8d5-14868883be84/missing-xaml-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=csharpide it might be your solution.

Comment: That's the same link that I already mentioned in my OP. Didn't resolve my issue when I tried

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Additionally I remarked the XAML items were missing from the Fonts and Colors section of Visual Studio settings.

After I ran `devenv /Setup` from an elevated command prompt, the XAML items were back in the settings and I could see colors in the XAML editor.

Answer (score 7):

I my case the problem was fixed by switching to different color scheme and then back to the one I use.